# I need to cast a class type to object type , Need to cast c1 to object2

Tags: java

The first method returns a class type and the second method returns an object type. I need to cast the class1 to object2 type

```
{
    //The return type is Class
    Class c1 = m.getReturnType();

    //The return type is object
    Object object2 = resultSet.getObject(i);
}
```

Comment: You are confused. There's no such thing as casting a variable to another variable.

Comment: Please clarify your question. "class1" does not show up in your code example at all. And "object2" is not a type, it's a variable name iin your code example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two ways to do the same.

1) Use, `c1.newInstance()` to get the object(throws checked exception to handle) and then cast the returned object to the required one

2) Use, `c1.cast(object2)` which will throw `ClassCastException` if instance cannot be created or the object is not of the class' instance (Preferred approach)

Comment: newInstance is not a cas at all, and calling cast() on non-generic Class is not too useful: you get back the same Object plus a possibility of exception. You may be better off using `isInstance`

Comment: I agree. newInstance() is not for the casting. I mentioned that to denote that instance can be created as it seemed to be that the user wanted the object after casting. cast() checks the isInstance() internally as well. That's why I mentioned that to be preferred approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the "cast" method on the Class class?

```
Class<T> c1 = m.getReturnType();

T casted = c1.cast(object2);
```